# What is a good/standard list of "simple English words" suitable for puzzling?

Tags: puzzle-creation, crosswords

Suppose I'm trying to computer-solve a puzzle, or computer-create a puzzle, where "every word in the *whatever* is a common English word." For example, intuitively, `BUNNY` is a common English word, `TAPIR` is borderline, and `EURYPTERID` is definitely *not* a common English word.

Where would I find a computer-readable wordlist of "common English words" in this sense?

I'm aware of the following resources and their disadvantages:

- The SOWPODS list (e.g. [here](https://www.wordgamedictionary.com/sowpods/download/sowpods.txt)). Major disadvantage: It contains obscure words such as `AALII`.
- "Basic English" lists (e.g. [here](http://ogden.basic-english.org/word2000.html)). Major disadvantages: They lack many common words such as `MOUSE`. They almost always lack declensions, e.g. the linked list contains `CAT` but not `CATS`.
- Crossword wordlists (e.g. [here](https://github.com/Quuxplusone/xword/tree/master/words)). Major disadvantages: They contain abbreviations such as `SSGT`, multi-word phrases such as `ATONCE`, and proper nouns such as `CYRUS`.
- The ["Up Goer Five" wordlist](https://splasho.com/blog/2013/01/17/a-bit-more-about-the-up-goer-five-text-editor/), constructed from [one of Wiktionary's computer-generated frequency lists](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Frequency_lists/Contemporary_fiction) plus the [Automatically Generated Inflection Database](http://wordlist.aspell.net/agid-readme/) (AGID). Major disadvantages: It lacks many common words such as `MOUSE`. Because it blindly uses AGID, it includes some surprising declensions, such as `CATTED` and `CATTING`.

Comment: who wants to go catting? I do :P

Answer (score 1):

I found the following additional resource.

- [2of12inf.txt](http://wordlist.aspell.net/12dicts-readme/#2of12inf) from the 12dicts package.

It successfully contains all of `BUNNY TAPIR CAT CATS MOUSE`.

It successfully omits all of `EURYPTERID AALII SSGT ATONCE CYRUS CATTED CATTING`.

UPDATE:

- Minor disadvantage: It contains some short words that I would consider "dubiously English" — `COS EM EMS EN ENS HES HI HIS HO HOS MA MAS MENS OM OMS PA PAS PIS RE REC REM` and so on.
- Minor disadvantage: It contains some words that IMHO do not pass the [breakfast table test](https://books.google.com/books?id=CZdmLIrJnZcC&pg=PT121) — `BITCH RAPE SHIT SHAT` and so on.

However, I'm still having good luck with this wordlist plus minor manual edits!